# Android, sleep a service

Tags: android, service, sleep

I'm implementing an app on Android. I've just added a new service that is called on boot-completed. This service creates a new thread that is simply a loop, making something minute after minute. To wait the next minute I used Thread.sleep(60000) but it doesn't work: after the waiting period no other action is performed. It seems that the app is closed or waiting permanentely.

Is there another way to make a loop-service avoiding Thread.sleep? I don't think it is a problem of code because if I call the main method of the service on the app starting it works (it is a problem related to the service)

Thank you in advance

I think the problem is related to the "scan media" of my LG L9 II.. when the "scan media" (I think is about my sd card) is completed all my service are killed (or something like it). Any suggestion?

Comment: why are you doing something every minute? that sounds like a quick-fire way of running through a user's battery

Comment: It check if there is any update inside a db.. any suggestion to do it without waiting?

Comment: is it a remote DB? use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to tell the device when the DB has been updated

Comment: Actually the processing won't be noticed on the battery.  The battery used by the processor is dominated by the display and radios.  Its a blip.  For proof, turn your decice into airplane mode, turn off GPS, and run a service that wakes frequently.  Your phone will last days.

Comment: cool.. I'll try it. Anyway, why do you think there is a problem using sleep with a service?

Comment: how about an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for minute-by-minute notification to execute a task?

Comment: I'm trying. I'm not so confident with it so maybe it can make bigger a trivial problem..

Answer (score 1):

Consider using AlarmManager to invoke your service. Below example illustrates how to establish repeating events every minute from AlarmManager.

```
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), ONE_MINUTE, pending);
```

Answer (score 0):

Services don't have their own thread, the share the main (UI) thread.  If you want to do something every minute, create a new thread and have it do something once a minute.

Comment: I have my service. Inside the service code, I create a new thread that contains a while(true){... Thread.sleep(60000);}
I don't know.. it is weird..

Answer (score 0):

There is almost never a good reason to use `Thread.sleep(...)` or explicitly create threads in Android.  If you need something to happen every 60 seconds, create a `Handler` and use its `postDelayed(...)` methods.  You can post a task that will re-post itself each time it runs.  Just make sure you cancel it when your app is shutting down.

Comment: That's incredible.. using the handler it gives me the same problem. 
I'm thinking that maybe it's a problem of my phone.. It's really weird.. For example in my previous code, it prints phase1,phase2,loop and then, after the sim card loading, it stops..